# Adobe Air: what browser does StageWebView use?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, stagewebview

I'm thinking about implementing a web view in my iOS app, but I haven't been able to find any reference as to what browser does `StageWebView` use.

I suspect the browser will be different depending on the system used. So, on iOS it should be Safari... but who knows.

Can someone point me to some reference where it states what browser it's using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html), StageWebView uses internal webkit.

Comment: You looked better than me :) i'll remove my answer since this makes more sense